# How to draw the gradient in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-graphics

I want to draw the Circular progress view with gradient as image :

[Design Image](http://www.imagesup.net/dt-414092455137.png)

I tried the below code but the result color is not correct. This is my code:

```
   //draw gradient

    CGFloat colors [] = {
        1.0, 0.7,
        0.2, 0.4

    };

    CGFloat locations[] = { 0.0, 1.0 };


    CGColorSpaceRef baseSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(); // gray colors want gray color space


    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(baseSpace, colors, locations, 2);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(baseSpace), baseSpace = NULL;

    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextAddPath(context, progressPath);
    CGContextClip(context);

    CGRect boundingBox = CGPathGetBoundingBox(progressPath);
    CGPoint gradientStart = CGPointMake(0.0, CGRectGetMinY(boundingBox));
    CGPoint gradientEnd   = CGPointMake(1.0, CGRectGetMaxY(boundingBox));

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, gradientStart, gradientEnd, 0);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient), gradient = NULL;
    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

The `progressPath` is the progress line with color :

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:21/255.0f green:182/255.0f blue:217/255.0f alpha:1.0]
```

UPDATE:

This is an image my code produced: [Result Image](http://www.imagesup.net/dt-314092783984.png)
The result image is not the same the design, the color is not the same. I dont know why.

Please help me to correct this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oops, my answer assumes you want an angle gradient, but upon closer examination, it looks like the image actually does use a linear gradient. Can you please post an image of the image this code produces, so we can see what's wrong with the output?

Comment: Instead of drawing gray colors with an alpha channel on top of blue, try using RGB colors that you sample from the original image. By my measurement, they should be RGB(78, 95, 99) and RGB(139, 206, 227).

Answer (score 0):

The kind of gradient you are looking for, where the color varies as a function of the angle around a center point, is called an angle gradient. Unfortunately, iOS does not have a built-in way to draw angle gradients, but you can do it using an open-source library such as [paiv/AngleGradientLayer](https://github.com/paiv/AngleGradientLayer).

Comment: I think I used the wrong gradient color. Can you please help me? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Working code:**

```
- (void) setGradientWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    //create the gradient
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = frame;
    //this example is white-black gradient, change it to the color you want..
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor], (id)[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor], nil];
    gradient.cornerRadius = frame.size.height/2.0f;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

    CALayer *whiteCircle = [CALayer layer];
    whiteCircle.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x + 10, frame.origin.y + 10, frame.size.width - 20, frame.size.height - 20);
    whiteCircle.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    whiteCircle.cornerRadius = whiteCircle.frame.size.width/2.0f;
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:whiteCircle atIndex:1];

    CALayer *whitesquare = [CALayer layer];
    whitesquare.frame = CGRectMake(50, frame.size.height - 20, 25, 25);
    whitesquare.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
    whitesquare.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-20.0 / 180.0 * M_PI, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    [self.view.layer insertSublayer:whitesquare atIndex:2];
}
```

to call the method:

```
[self setGradientWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
```

PS. change the color to the color of gradient to the color you want:

Comment: Thanks but it is not work in my case. I draw it in drawRect(). I updated my question. Pls. check. Thanks